# Scorecount on collision

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am new to objective-c (two days, to be exact) and i am needing this for a project in school.

i am trying to make the score count/countdown timer increase when two UIImageView collide, but now when my character is passing through the frame, it is increasing the score count/countdown timer more than once. Is there anyway I could correct this?

Thanks in advance

```
-(void) specificActions {
charmovement = 18;


if (CGRectIntersectsRect(mainchar.frame, fruit1.frame)) {
    score = +1;
    secondsCount = secondsCount+10;
    fruit1.hidden = YES;
    scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d",score];

}
```

Comment: when do you call the specificActions  method and how often ?

Comment: You are writing a game. Use a game engine like SpriteKit or Cocos2D.

Comment: @Fogmeister i only need this as a single stage demo and i am pretty sure it can be done with a single view.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question I'm going to be general in my answer.

The trouble is that you are always checking if the reacts intersect, rather than checking for the first intersect.

Easiest way to solve it is so have a variable that stores whether or not the current event has been recorded. You can then test as follows.

- if the check variable is no and the rects intersect, increment the touch count, and set the variable to YES.
- if the variable is YES and the rects intersect, do nothing.
- if the variable is YES and the rects do not intersect, set the variable to NO
- if the variable is NO and the rects do not intersect,do nothing.

Comment: thanks, i will try that out
ps, i have no prior exp in programming